# Is it appropriate to flag questions that should be protected?

Tags: support, flags, moderation

In the past, here and on other SE sites, I flagged many times to protect some questions that I think they should be. Every time, it's ended fine.

In every case, question

1. has attracted a lot a viewers in the past (10k+)
2. has been reactivated recently
3. has a lot of "poor" answers from new users

Today, I flagged [a question with a lot of views, a nice answer, but with 3 bad answers (one has been deleted since).](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/230114/how-to-turn-off-game-notifications-in-windows-10) This question was actived today. The flag's review was :

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
>   content that requires their intervention

**Is it appropriate to flag questions that should be protected ?**

In other words, does this kind of situation need a moderator's intervention ?

Comment: Personally, I don't think the question in question requires protection, having received only one answer recently, and only one answer warranting  deletion.

Comment: Don't read too much into one declined flag; just means whichever mod looked at it decided *in this case* it didn't need action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That question only has one new answer in any recent sense and one deleted answer. The point of protection is to keep questions that have *already* gotten a bunch of "me too" or non-answers - it is intended to be reactive to a problem rather than proactive, as it eliminates the possibility of a new user being able to come in and post an awesome answer.

In general, if you see a question that's attracting a lot of non answers or "I have this problem too" sorts of stuff, flag it for protection. (Although there is a point after a certain number of deleted answers that a question will be auto-protected by the Community user.)

If it's just something you think *might* reach that point but actually hasn't, then maybe keep an eye on it (or trust the community will catch it).

In short - we don't really preemptively protect questions, as it restricts the possibility for new users to jump in with insights.